# Prevent UIKeyboard from showing on UISearchBar tap

Tags: iphone, ios, events, uisearchbar, uikeyboard

I have my own custom keyboard in a uiview which i'm adding to the UIWindow in certain situations.

I switch between standard UIKeyboard and my custom keyboard with a button.

Problem: when i have my custom keyboard already shown on screen and i tap the UISearchBar i get the standard UIkeyboard shown above mine.
What I expect is to supress showing of Sandard UIKeyboard when i have my custom one already showing on screen.

I intercept keyboardwillshow event but it seems at this event is too late to do that.

I also tried subclassing UISearchBar and get control over its UITextField to get the Shouldbegintextediting but it doesn't seem to work ... (FYI UISearchBar doesn't have shouldbegintextediting event in the protocol. Its only for uitextfiled).

Also, there is no such thing as 'inputView' property in UISearchBar.

I tested this on iOS 5.1.

Anyone with experience on this kind of issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `inputView` of the search field to your custom keyboard.

Comment: there is no inputView property in the UISearchBar.
I have updated my question so that this is more clear.

Comment: Then you'll have to build your own search field.

Comment: Yes, I was about to do that. Thank you Jesper. I just thought there might be a more 'natural' way.